# A simulation: What's the difference between linear MPC and LQG?

Tags: control-theory, optimal-control, simulation, linear-control, kalman-filter

I thought it would be good to do a cooperation between basic MPC and basic LQR. So i hook up a state space model for simulation.

$$\dot x = Ax(t) + Bu(t) \\
y(t) = Cx(t) + Du(t)$$

Code:

```
delay = 0;
A = [0 1; -30 -3];
B = [0; 1];
C = [1 0];

% Create state space
sys = ss(delay, A, B, C); % D = Automatic
```

Which I convert to a discrete model.

$$x(k+1) = Ax(k) + Bu(k) \\
y(k) = Cx(k) + Du(k)$$

Code:

```
% Convert to discrete
h = 0.03;
sysd = c2d(sys, h)
```

To find the LQR gain matrix $L$ and kalman gain matrix $K$ i use the discrete Riccati equation, where $Q$ and $R$ are tuning matrices.

$$0 = A^TXA - X - A^TXB(R + B^TXB)^{-1}B^TXA + Q$$
$$L = (B^TXB + R)^{-1}(B^TXA)$$
$$K = (CXC^T + R)^{-1}(CXA^T)$$
Code:

```
% Find LQR control law
Q = [2 0; 0 1];
R = [3];
L = lqr(sysd, Q, R)

% Find kalman gain matrix K
Q = [1 0; 0 0.5];
R = [0.3];
K = lqe(sysd, Q, R)
```

Then I create signals for my LQG system. In this case, I will only write out MATLAB code because I don't know how to write the definition of this:

Code:

```
% Create signals
r = linspace(5, 5, 800); % Reference signal
d = linspace(0, 0, 800); % Disturbance signal - All zeros
n = 0.2*randn(1, 800); % White noise signal
t = linspace(0, 10, 800); % Time vector
```

Now I create my LQG state space model with state feedback:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
x(k+1)\\ 
\tilde x(k+1)
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
(A-BL) & BL\\ 
0 & (A-KC)
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
x(k)\\ 
\tilde x(k)
\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}
BK_r & B_d & 0\\ 
 0& B_d & -KB_n
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
r\\ 
d\\ 
n
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
y\\ 
y_m\\ 
u
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
C &0 \\ 
C & 0\\ 
-L &L 
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
x(k)\\ 
\tilde x(k)
\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 &0 \\ 
0 &  0& B_n\\ 
K_r & 0 &0 
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
r\\ 
d\\ 
n
\end{bmatrix}$$

Where $K_r$ is the precompensator feed forward factor for better tracking.

$$K_r = \frac{1}{C(I-(A-BL))^{-1}B}$$

Code:

```
% Create LQG state space model
Bd = [0; 0]; % Disturbance matrix
Bn = [1]; % Noise matrix for mesurement
LQG = lqgreg(sysd, L, K, Bd, Bn);
```

And now I will simulate the system:

Code:

```
% Simulate
lsim(LQG, [r; d; n], t); % y1 = Filtered, y2 = Noisy, y3 = input signal
```

The result is:

[image]

And we will do the same with MPC. To create the contol law $L$ for MPC, i need to find matrix prediction matrices $F$ and $\Phi$ first.

$$F = \begin{bmatrix}
CA\\ 
CA^2\\ 
CA^3\\ 
\vdots \\ 
CA^{N_p}
\end{bmatrix} , \Phi = \begin{bmatrix}
CB &0  &0  &\cdots   & 0\\ 
CAB & CB & 0  & \cdots & 0\\ 
CA^2B& CAB & 0 &\cdots  &0 \\ 
 \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots &\vdots \\ 
CA^{N_p-1}B & CA^{N_p-2}B & CA^{N_p-3}B & \cdots  & CA^{N_p-N_c}B 
\end{bmatrix}$$

I say that prediction horizon is $N_p = 10$ and control horizon is $N_c = 5$. To get the MPC control law $L$ and precompensator factor $K_r$. Source litterature: "*Model Predictive Control System Design and Implementation Using MATLAB*" by Liuping Wang, page 16.

$$K_r = \overset{N_c}{\begin{bmatrix}
I_{mxm} & o_{mxm} & o_{mxm} & \cdots & o_{mxm} 
\end{bmatrix}}(\Phi^T\Phi + \bar R)^{-1}\Phi^T \bar R_s$$

$$L = \overset{N_c}{\begin{bmatrix}
I_{mxm} & o_{mxm} & o_{mxm} & \cdots & o_{mxm} 
\end{bmatrix}}(\Phi^T\Phi + \bar R)^{-1}\Phi^T F$$

Where:

$$\bar R = R_{\omega} I_{N_c x N_c}$$

There $ R_{\omega}$ is a tuning factor and $I_{N_c x N_c}$ is a square identity matrix with dimension $N_c$ and $m$ is the number of output signals.

Also this is important too:

$$\bar R_s = \overset{N_p}{\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 
\end{bmatrix}^T}$$

Anyway! We will still use the LQG-state space model, with just a change of control law $L$ and precompensator factor $K_r$.

Code:

```
Np = 10; % Prediction horizon
Nc = 5; % Control horizon
Rw = 0.0001; % Tuning parameter "R omega".
MPC = mpcreg(sysd, Np, Nc, Rw, K, Bd, Bn);
```

And then do a new smulation:

Code:

```
figure(2) % new figure to plot on
lsim(MPC, [r; d; n], t); % y1 = Filtered, y2 = Noisy, y3 = input signal
```

And the result is:

[image]

As you can see. MPC model can predict the future states and do better tracking of trajectories.

**Questions:**

1. Is it suppose that $R_{\omega}$ should be so low as 0.0001?
2. What's the really difference between LQG and MPC in this case? Isn't LQR also a predictable controller?
3. Does my controller be better if I sett the control horizon and predict horizon even further?
4. Why are the result from MPC much more noisy that the LQG result? The observer is the same.
5. Is it better that I compute the $K_r$ for MPC by using
   $$K_r = \frac{1}{C(I-(A-BL))^{-1}B}$$

Instead?

Here is the code of mpcreg function.

https://github.com/DanielMartensson/matavecontrol/blob/master/sourcecode/mpcreg.m

You can also download my library and install it easy on your MALTAB or GNU Octave.
https://github.com/DanielMartensson/matavecontrol

**EDIT:**

Here is a simulation with saturation of the states. Only available for Matavecontrol.

```
% Create matricies
delay = 0;
A = [0 1; -30 -3];
B = [0; 1];
C = [1 0];

% Create state space
sys = ss(delay, A, B, C); % D = Automatic

% Convert to discrete
h = 0.03;
sysd = c2d(sys, h)

% Find LQR control law
Q = [1 0; 2 0.5];
R = [2];
L = lqr(sysd, Q, R)

% Find kalman gain matrix K

K = lqe(sysd, Q, R)

% Create signals
r = linspace(1, 1, 800); % Reference signal 
d = linspace(0, 0, 800); % Discurbance signal - All zeros
n = 0.2*randn(1, 800); % White noise signal
t = linspace(0, 10, 800); % Time vector


% Create LQG state space model
Bd = [0; 0]; % Discurbance matrix
Bn = [1]; % Noise matrix for mesurement
[LQG, Kr] = lqgreg(sysd, L, K, Bd, Bn)

% Simulate
nlsim(LQG, [r; d; n], t, [0;0;0;0], [0 2; 0 2; 0 2; 0 2]); % y1 = Filtered, y2 = Noisy, y3 = input signal

% Now do MPC
Np = 10; % Prediction horizon
Nc = 5; % Control horizon
Rw = 0.0001; % Tuning parameter
[MPC, Lmpc, Krmpc] = mpcreg(sysd, Np, Nc, Rw, K, Bd, Bn);


% Simulate
figure(2) % new figure to plot on
nlsim(MPC, [r; d; n], t, [0;0;0;0], [0 2; 0 2; 0 2; 0 2]); % y1 = Filtered, y2 = Noisy, y3 = input signal
```

Results:

LQG

[image]

MPC

[image]

Comment: You haven't tuned your LQR so you can't make those assessments. Decrease your R and it will start tracking much better. Again methods are not competitive. You can't compare methods you have to compare results. This is a control theory nonsense poisoning the literature. Unless you come up with a 1-1 mathematical mapping between resulting controllers this comparison is just wishful.

Comment: @percusse What? Ofc I have tuned my LQR with Q and R. I would say it it's reverse. The literature of control theory poisoning itself due to the lack of pedagogy.

Comment: For each set of Q,R you can design equally bad or good MPC controller. You don't know which one corresponds to which controller.

Comment: But if I use the same Q and R for both LQG and MPC?

Comment: Infinite and finite horizon problems do not share the same optimum.

Comment: So LQR is for infinitive control and predictive horizon and MPC it's variable for the user?

Comment: The real power of MPC comes from handling explicit constraints on signal amplitudes or the input constraints incorporated in the finite time optimization scheme. LQR does it only via relative weighting (Q vs. R) and assumes infinite time horizon. If you have more sophisticated constraints it won't allow you to consider some of them. Since the prediction horizon is short you can actually implement aggresive estimators too which would lead to very fragile LQ regulators. So the methods are not comparable. It's an engineering art rather than some formal classification

Comment: @percusse Thank you. That's explains why the are more noise in MPC that LQR in this case.

Comment: @percusse Is MPC with constranits an open loop controller?

Comment: For deterministic cases, it is both in the sense that we compute the input in an open loop fashion but the optimization problem is setup from the past data hence closed loop.

Comment: @percusse Ok. I understand. No control law $L$  in other words?

Comment: Yes a time-varying controller instead.

Comment: @percusse Why not use saturation on the input instead to compute the inputs with QP?

Comment: Because the current optimal solution relies on providing that output magnitude. If there is a saturation then you can get instabilities. Imagine an aggressive controller that will supply 25 volts for a very short amount of time and then quickly counter it and then slowly stop. If you clip it, all bets are off.

Comment: @percusse Ok. It's a question about stability.